# How to physically remove WiFi from 4B?

Tags: wifi, pi-4, hardware

I am closely following Scott Young's training on working with deep focus.

I have a new 8GB Raspberry Pi 4B along with an Samsung 870 SSD and NVMe to USB 3 converter - I am working just right.

But as recommended, I want to simply eliminate the possibility of having internet without plugging in a cable which lies in my (always crowded) hall.

So:
**how can I safely physically remove WiFi from my 4B RPi?**

I did try getting rid of the firmware - first it made the device non-bootable, I had to re-install and OS and load everything again. And worse, if I have had too many chocolates, I will jump any fence hoop or obstacle course to get to my favorite .... site. So software disablement is not a solution.

I can't live with less than 4GB RAM, and USB boot is another important thing I guess older RPis don't have.

Comment: More people on this site have trouble getting WiFi working! If you don't configure it it **won't do anything**.

Comment: If your concern is radiation there are guidelines on disabling wireless, but you have failed to explain ANYTHING you tried. You haven't even noted what OS.

Comment: what does Scott Young's training have to do with Raspberry Pi WiFi?

Answer (score 0):

Without experience with surface-mount desoldering tools, this isn't possible. On the official forum, a moderator suggests that it might be

> … [sufficient to just remove the main wifi/bluetooth chip](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=262286#p1685324)

There were no reports of this being tried and being successful. You may accidentally render your computer unusable.

The most recent/useful Raspberry Pi that came with no wifi is the Raspberry Pi Model 2B. It uses the same SoC as the Raspberry Pi Model 3B, except runs at only 900 MHz. It is still available in limited quantities, but is in demand from security applications which require limited RF emissions.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using *Raspberry Pi OS* and the default `dhcpcd` you can prevent the Pi from configuring an interface.

---

Add `denyinterfaces wlan0` to the end of the file (but above any other added interface lines).